# SELECT row WHERE parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query based on a get variable. I use the variable to specify which rows the query should find. When there is no get variable set, i want the query to get all rows.

Earlier in the code i set the $category variable to be either 1,2,3.

```
WHERE products.category = $category
```

The question: How do i make it get all the rows if no variable is set?

Answer (score 1):

dont add the where clause or just

```
WHERE products.category in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is:

```
$wc = (isset($category)) ? "WHERE products.category = '$category'" : "";
$sql = "SELECT *
       FROM products
       " . $wc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `WHERE` clause if the variable has no value.

Comment: ^ And do NOT ever put directly any input from the user without sanitizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Or

check if $category is set then

use
products.category = $category

else
1

so the result will be either

WHERE products.category = $category

or

Where 1

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE  products.category =(case when $category IS not null 
then $category else products.category end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would add the where statement conditionally (if only the 1,2,3 categories exist), but if the category id's are fixed, you could try using;

```
if (!isset($category))
{
    $category = "1,2,3";
}

WHERE products.category in ($category)
```